# Google Play Game Services crashes after sending invite

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've been implementing a multiplayer game with Google Play Game Services and was at the point where i could send messages between clients.
Now google play services keeps crashing everytime i send an invite, login and everything else works just fine.
This happens with my app as well as the multiplayer sample app from google.
I think the crashes started after a ADT update.

Logcat:

```
06-04 03:37:56.610: W/dalvikvm(2258): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/google/android/gms/games/jingle/Libjingle;
06-04 03:37:56.610: D/AndroidRuntime(2258): Shutting down VM
06-04 03:37:56.610: W/dalvikvm(2258): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a1b930)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at ajd.<init>(SourceFile:361)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at ajd.a(SourceFile:476)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at ara.<init>(SourceFile:120)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at com.google.android.gms.games.service.RealTimeMatchAndroidService.onBind(SourceFile:73)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:2624)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load games_rtmp_jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/app/GmsCore.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/GmsCore]: findLibrary returned null
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     at com.google.android.gms.games.jingle.Libjingle.<clinit>(SourceFile:38)
06-04 03:37:56.625: E/AndroidRuntime(2258):     ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build system is probably generating an APK that's missing components. I would advise you to rebuild your development environment from scratch (new workspace, new IDE installation, new everything). It's often easier to rebuild from scratch than to pinpoint the exact setup issue that went wrong.

1. Delete your workspace
2. Delete the bin/, gen/, project.properties etc on all projects. In summary, delete everything that was generated by an IDE or a build system.
3. Start with a fresh workspace
4. Import the Google Play services library project into the fresh workspace
5. Import BaseGameUtils into the workspace
6. Add the Google Play Services library as a reference on BaseGameUtils
7. Import your project into the workspace
8. Make sure your project is referencing BaseGameUtils

Try to generate the APK agian.